# Can't override scala abstract function with lambda

Tags: scala

If I write :

```
trait Aaa { 
  def a(i: Int): Boolean 
}

class Bbb extends Aaa { 
  def a = (x: Int) => x == 42 
}
```

But it can't compile, I get the following error :

```
override.scala:7: class Bbb needs to be abstract, since method a in trait Aaa of type (i: Int)Boolean is not defined
class Bbb extends Aaa {
      ^
Compilation Failed
```

Why ?

Comment: Why - it is a good question, but what do you need it for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trait `Aaa` defines a ***method*** `a` but the class `Bbb` defines a ***function value*** `a`. A method is not the same as a function value is Scala, so the definition of `a` in your class `Bbb` does not implement the `a` in `Aaa`. Since `Aaa.a` does not have a definition, the class must be declared `abstract`.

It will work if you do this instead:

```
class Bbb extends Aaa {
  def a(x:Int) = x == 42
}
```

If you really need a function value rather than a method, you need to declare another `val` and use an **eta-expansion** like this:

```
class Bbb extends Aaa {
  def a(x:Int) = x == 42
  val b = a _
}
```

`b` can now be passed as a function argument to calls such as `filter` whereas `a` cannot.

Answer (score 3):

The trait `Aaa` prescribes that there must be a method `a` with one argument of type `Int` and return type `Boolean`.

The class `Bbb` has a method `a` without any arguments and return type `(Int => Boolean)`, which is the same as `Function1[Int, Boolean]`.

So, the method `a` in `Bbb` has the wrong number of arguments and a different return type.

It shouldn't compile, so it doesn't compile. No problem whatsoever.

---

A general remark:

```
def f(x1: T1, ..., xn: Tn): Y = body
```

is not syntactic sugar for

```
val f = (x1: T1, ..., xn: Tn): Y => body
```

The former is a method, the latter is a value of type `FunctionN[T1, ..., Tn, Y]`. While the two definitions might be treated in the same way in some other languages influenced by ML, it is not the case in Scala. Scala differentiates between methods and functions.